# 'std::list<_Ty>::push_back' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const std::list<_Ty>' to 'std::list<_Ty> &'

Tags: c++, constants

I'm getting this error message when try to compile the following

```
void MyClass::MyFunc() const
{
      int i= 0;
      myList.push_back(i);
}
```

I've already had to add the const to the function, despite it returning `void`, to fix an identical problem with the invocation of the function itself, but now that it's occurring with a member of the STL, I'm thinking something is very wrong with my code. For reference, the error was

```
cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const MyClass' to 'MyClass &'
```

I actually have very little idea of what's going on since I inherited this from someone with a very abusive relationship with coding standards and best practices. If someone could tell me what problem this is a symptom of and what I should be looking for in the code, it would help me a lot.

Comment: You can't mark a member func as "read-only" and then expect it to write without issues.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ke686zh(v=vs.110).aspx
Also, note the difference between "const int Func()" and "int Func() const".

Comment: There is some misunderstanding about the meaning of `const` here: _I've already had to add the const to the function, despite it returning void_. `const` has nothing to do with what the function returns (unless it returns a pointer/reference to a member). You should have a look at the original error (the one you got before you added `const`) and try to understand why the object of which you call `MyFunc()` is a constant object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` on a method means that it can't modify the instance it is called on, including any instance members.

You need to take a look at the code base and distinguish between methods that can *modify* the class instance (which should not be `const`) and those that just provide information about the class instance (which should be `const`).

Answer (score 2):

If `myList` is a data member of `MyClass`, with `push_back()` you are modifying the `myList` data member (so you are modifying the instance of `MyClass` pointed by `this`), so `MyFunc()` method can't be marked as `const`.

Answer (score 0):

$9.3.1/3: When an id-expression (5.1) that is not part of a class member access syntax (5.2.5) and not used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1) is used in a member of class X in a context where this can be used (5.1.1), if name lookup (3.4) resolves the name in the id-expression to a non-static non-type member of some class C, and if either the id-expression is potentially evaluated or C is X or a base class of X, the id-expression is transformed into a class member access expression (5.2.5) using (*this) (9.3.2) as the postfix-expression to
the left of the . operator.

What this means is that the expression

```
myList.push_back(i);
```

is treated as

```
(*this).myList.push_back(i);
```

$9.3.1/4: A non-static member function may be declared const, volatile, or const volatile. These cv-qualifiers affect the type of the this pointer (9.3.2).

$9.3.2/1: In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of this in a member function of a class X is X*. If the member function is declared const, the type of this is const X*, if the member function is declared volatile, the type of this is volatile X*, and if the member function is declared const volatile, the type of this is const volatile X*.

In summary, what this means is that type of 'this' in your member function which is 'const' is 'MyClass const *'. Effectively, it means that `Myclass::MyFunc` is not allowed to modify the state of the object pointed to by the 'this' pointer.

Assuming myList is of type std::list, the method std::list::push_back modifies the instance variable 'myList' as it inserts the value of 'i' in the list.

But this breaks the semantics of the 'const' member function `MyClass::MyFunc` which promises that it won't modify the state of the object.

So, you really need to remove the 'const' from this member function or use const_cast to remove the constness for this specific operation.